# boto3 - s3 global configuration

Tags: amazon-s3, boto3

I have a scenario where all of the objects being written through bot3 have to be encrypted (ServerSideEncryption AKA SSE) using a predefined key.

I don't want to go over all of the places in the code where we're uploading objects to S3.
Instead, I do want to find a way to configure each S3 client so that the SSE will be enforced implicitly.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

[I've posted it to AWS](https://console.aws.amazon.com/support/cases?region=us-east-1#/5997239471/en), there is no such option, only explicit call.